# Keep only matching records on QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

Is there any way of doing the "keep only matching records" on QGIS when working with joint tables?

(This is an option on ArcGIS, but not on QGIS as far as I know)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do a three step process.

1. Join the tables you want. You will get rows which will contain NULL values (the nonmatching ones)
2. Select all the none NULL rows with a select expression:

   ```
   "my_joined_field" IS  NOT NULL
   ```

Where "my_joined_field" is a random field from the joined table

3. Save the selection with the "save as.." context menu and choose "Save only selected features"